# Extend facebook access token

Tags: facebook, access-token

In my web application, i have a facebook login button that allow user to connect, each time user click the button, i redirect the user to oAuth dialogue with the scopes. Normally if the user already autorised all the asking permission, the redirection is transparent and facebook send me back a new access token that have 60 days life times. Since yesterday(or may be sooner), i noticed that with the same process facebook will not return an access token with 60 days but the actual valid access token with the remain expiration. Is there a change in the facebook platform?

Comment: Did you enable this: Deprecate offline access: Enabled

Comment: There is a bug in Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241373692605971

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) say about this:

> If the call is made while there is still a valid access_token for that
>   user, the returned access_token from this second call will remain the
>   same and only the expiration time will be extended. Again, **calling
>   this multiple times during the same day will result only in the first
>   call extending the expiration time**.

Are you trying to extend the token more than once per day?